# Dealing with lack of work in new job efficiently and professionally

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, time-management, work-time

I joined this IT company 3 months ago for my first job as `C` developer. I graduated last summer as software engineer and to make things clear, this is not my first "Getting in touch" with professional IT world as I had a six months intern-ship with another IT company for my graduation project.

So my problem is simply that I have been assigned no tasks/projects yet. It looks like the project I was recruited to work on was cancelled right after they hired me.

I was told this the first day I joined the DEV team and it wasn't such a big problem to me because for the first couple of weeks, It was all about documents reading and setting my machine and work environment. My boss was frank with me telling me that we have nothing going on right now (our team is me and my boss only) and he assigned some bug fixing to me which I have completed.

Now for the third consecutive week I am doing nothing, I am working on an open-space so doing some reading or working on something else is no option as everyone will notice that and It is really annoying to be seen not working.

It is quiet a situation and I feel very uncomfortable because not only everyone knows that I am doing nothing , but also I feel like I am loosing my "coding power". What is the proper way to deal with this situation ? Is talking to my boss an option ? Will this make him (my boss) feel that he is not good enough boss to me ? Any kind of advice would help.

Comment: Flagged as a dupe of one specific question but [there are many more](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+ask+work)

Answer (score 3):

Refactor some code, investigate a new version control system, investigate a new language to use, improve the make environment so the code builds from one command, automate testing so every time a check in occurs a test suite is performed on the code, etc.

These are just a few things I've done when I run low on work assigned to me. I will spend a day or two researching/investigating one of these items, develop a plan, and then present the plan to my boss. "Hey this new version control system does X, Y, and Z. I think it would help us in these areas and would take me about X weeks to migrate. What do you think?" At this point he will determine if he has anything more urgent for you to work on and if so, will assign that to you.